# Reduction formula for characteristic polynomial of a graph

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Q) Let $p(G,x)$ be the characteristic polynomial of the Adjacency matrix of a graph $G$. Suppose $v_i$ is a vertex of degree $1$ of $G$ and $v_j$ is $v_i's$ neighbor and suppose $G_1 = G-\{v_i\},G_2 = G-\{v_i,v_j\}$, then show that

$$p(G,x) = xp(G_1,x)-p(G_2,x)$$

It must be a simple  expansion of determinant along some row/column but its not occurring to me right now. Thanks.

Comment: Is $\{v_i, v_j\}$ a set of two vertices being removed or the edge between them?

Comment: @NikoWielopolski It is the set of two vertices removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix for $G$. Without loss of generality, we can permute the vertices so that $v_i$ corresponds to the first row/column, and $v_j$ to the second row and column. Since $v_i$ is degree $1$, we have
$$xI-A = \begin{pmatrix}x & -1 & \mathbf{0}^\mathrm{T} \\ -1 & x & Y^\mathrm{T} \\ \mathbf{0} & Y & Z\end{pmatrix},$$
where $Y$ and $Z$ are matrices of the appropriate sizes. Note that $Z$ is just $xI-A_{ij}$, where $A_{ij}$ the adjacency matrix of $G\backslash\{v_i,v_j\}$. Taking a cofactor expansion along the first row, we have
$$\det(xI-A) = x\begin{vmatrix}x & Y^\mathrm{T} \\ Y & Z\end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} -1 & Y^\mathrm{T} \\ \mathbf{0} & Z\end{vmatrix}.$$
The first determinant is just $\det(xI-A_i)$, where $A_i$ is the adjacency matrix of $G\backslash\{v_i\}$. The second determinant evaluates to $\det(Z) = \det(xI-A_{ij})$. Therefore we have
$$\det(xI-A) = x\det(xI-A_i) - \det(xI-A_{ij}),$$
as required.